# Communication between non-activity classes using Interface

Tags: android, interface, android-fragments

I have set up a TouchableWrapper class for my map to detect when there is interaction from the user, the code was initially setup to send notifications via the override method to an activity,. However my map is in a Fragment and I would like to receive these overrides. So far I keep getting a null pointer exception.

TouchableWrapper Class

```
public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

private long lastTouched = 0;
private static final long SCROLL_TIME = 200L; // 200 Milliseconds, but you
                                                // can adjust that to your
                                                // liking
private UpdateMapAfterUserInterection updateMapAfterUserInterection;

// public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
// super(context);
// // Force the host activity to implement the UpdateMapAfterUserInterection
// Interface
// // try {
// // updateMapAfterUserInterection = (UpdateMapAfterUserInterection)
// context;
// // } catch (ClassCastException e) {
// // throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() +
// " must implement UpdateMapAfterUserInterection");
// // }
// }

public TouchableWrapper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TouchableWrapper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setUpdateMapAfterUserInterection(updateMapAfterUserInterection);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        lastTouched = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (now - lastTouched > SCROLL_TIME) {
            // Update the map
            updateMapAfterUserInterection.onUpdateMapAfterUserInterection();
        }
        break;
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

// Map Activity must implement this interface
public interface UpdateMapAfterUserInterection {
    public void onUpdateMapAfterUserInterection();
}

public void setUpdateMapAfterUserInterection(UpdateMapAfterUserInterection mUpdateMapAfterUserInterection) {
    this.updateMapAfterUserInterection = mUpdateMapAfterUserInterection;
}
}
```

Here is how I've tried to use it in my Fragment class containing my map

```
TouchableWrapper tW = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
        tW.setUpdateMapAfterUserInterection(new UpdateMapAfterUserInterection() {

            @Override
            public void onUpdateMapAfterUserInterection() {
                Log.d("MAP", "TOUCHED? YEP");
            }
        });
```

How can I get this to work the way I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can call it from your FragmentActivity which started you map Fragment and then from there communicate it to map fragment.

Follow the android developer link below to communicate between fragmnet and its activity. It has sample code also:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html